Set datatypes in dynamic mapping json in ADF
I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that takes json  as input and loads the data  to a table in Sql server. now i have multiple tables to load so i am using a for each loop  to load multiple tables . hence need for dynamic mapping file. below is one of sample json mapping that i am currently having .
{   "type": "TabularTranslator",   "mappings": [     {       "source": {         "name": "Provider_Id",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Provider_Id",         "type": "String"       }     },         {       "source": {         "name": "Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       }     },     {       "source": {         "name": "Composite_Provider_Id_Identifier_Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Composite_Provider_Id_Identifier_Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       }     },      {       "source": {         "name": "Emr_Id",         "type": "Int"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Emr_Id",         "type": "Int"       }     }   ] }


now the problem here is when i use the above mapping where datatype in sink is String, it is creating column in sql server tables as nvarchar max datatype.
i am just trying to find if there is a way to define datatypes in sink like example Varchar(200).
I tried to give datatype that i want in target table like example below. But it always throws error.
{   "type": "TabularTranslator",   "mappings": [     {       "source": {         "name": "Provider_Id",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Provider_Id",         "type": "Varchar('250')"       }     },         {       "source": {         "name": "Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Provider_Type",         "type": "Varchar('250')"       }     },     {       "source": {         "name": "Composite_Provider_Id_Identifier_Provider_Type",         "type": "String"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Composite_Provider_Id_Identifier_Provider_Type",         "type": "Varchar('250')"       }     },      {       "source": {         "name": "Emr_Id",         "type": "Int"       },       "sink": {         "name": "Emr_Id",         "type": "Int"       }     }   ] }



Currently When ADF create the table and store the data into SQL server it by default creates a data type as nvarchar(max). you cannot specify the length of the string column in mapping.
To workaround it you can use the pre-copy script option to create the table with appropriate datatypes and sizes and it will store the data.


Thanks so much ,thats a great idea. if i dont come across any this this is what i will be doing :)
